# How to create url pattern with unknown number of @PathVariables in spring-mvc?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, path-variables

I am looking for single url pattern which can fit the following:

www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable10}/{pathvariable11}/{pathvariable12}
www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable20}/{pathvariable21}/{pathvariable22}
www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable30}/{pathvariable31}/{pathvariable32}/{pathvariable33}/{pathvariable34}

```
                .
                .
                .'
```

www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable80}/{pathvariable81}/{pathvariable82}
www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable90}/{pathvariable91}/{pathvariable92}
www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable100}/{pathvariable101}/{pathvariable102}/{pathvariable103}/{pathvariable104}

Comment: Are you sure that this is what you want to do? Path variables, as the name suggests, are variables showed in the url, is that what you want? I guess no, you may want to consider using parameters, or filling a list.

Comment: eg www.example.com/asset/{pathvariable10}/{pathvariable11}/{pathvariable12} could be www.example.com/asset/switch/cisco-switch/cisco-catalyst-4000. A company can have hundreds of assets with such categorisation, so the question is valid

Comment: Still think that it is wrong to put such information in path variables.

Comment: Why ? but I find it to be CEO friendly than using something like www.example.com/?asset=pathvariable10/pathvariable11/pathvariable12

Comment: So, I guess that you will have some API which will map this requests. Try to imagine how difficult would be to use it. You will have a method with lot of variables.

Comment: My problem is I dont know how many variables will be there and that is why I want  to handle it in general sense,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the possible answer to this question is using:

```
`@RequestMapping(value = "/asset/**", method = RequestMethod.GET`)
```

This will allow any number of @PathVariables.However to get the actual values of the variables we can use:

```
String requestedUri = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.PATH_WITHIN_HANDLER_MAPPING_ATTRIBUTE);
```

.Search for whatever we want in the string,`requestedUri`. For example:

```
if (requestedUri.toLowerCase().contains("new")){
registerNewAsset();
}else if (requestedUri.toLowerCase().contains("edit")){
editAsset(asset_id);
}else if (requestedUri.toLowerCase().contains("delete")){
deleteAsset(asset_id);
}else if (requestedUri.toLowerCase().contains("list")){
listAssets()
}
```

The rest is history.